# Illegal Type promotion to unsupported type

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing

I am porting some general purpose C code to an audio DSP, with a 24 bit architecture. 16 and 32 bit math functions have been supplied with the ASIP compiler and BSP materials. The basic types of int, long , and to the degree it makes sense char are supported- Alongside int16, int32, int24 and int48.

Despite int24 and int16 having the same base, and what should be an almost identical in memory representation, when a calculation involves both types the numbers are all promoted to doubles. Unfortunately double does not map onto any of the supported types.

Are there any tips or tricks to avoid type promotion, other than being very strict with data-types and representations?

Comment: Please show us a bit of the involved code.

Comment: There's no way they will get promoted to doubles unless you explicitly decided to involve float numbers. Please post an example of the specific, problematic code. Also what is "int16" etc, that's no standard type so please post those typedefs.

Comment: Those types are int16_t, int32_t, etc, I neglected the '_t' on them...

The most recent case was:
`int32_t variable_1 = variable_2`
where variable 2 was an int16_t. And I "solved" this by putting both values in int16_t type.

What's even better is that the platform should have no concept of floats whatsoever.